# How internalPointer method works

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt

In a code below both `Car()` and `Plane()` inherit from `Base` class.

[image]

Every time `QTableView` is clicked `OnClick()` method receives a `QModelIndex` as its incoming argument.

Inside of scope of `OnClick()` method `node=index.internalPointer()` line returns an instance of either Car or Plane defined in model's `self.items` variable.

Model's `self.items` is not a list but a sub-classed hierarchical variable. Yet `internalPointer()` method does make it appear it indexes a list variable with the supplied to it as an argument the row number of QModelIndex that was clicked.

I would appreciate if you supply more details on how `internalPointer()` method works so I could design Plane, Car and Base classes accordingly (so they return what I want and not what `internalPointer()`.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Base(object):    
    def __init__(self, name, parentNode=None):        
        self._name = name
        self._children=[]
        self._parentNode=parentNode
        if parentNode is not None:
            parentNode.addChild(self)
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "BaseNode"
    def addChild(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name
    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]
    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)
    def getParent(self):
        return self._parentNode
    def row(self):
        if self._parentNode is not None:
            return self._parentNode._children.index(self)

class Car(Base):    
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Car, self).__init__(name, parent)        
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "CarNode"
class Plane(Base):    
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Plane, self).__init__(name, parent)        
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "PlaneNode"

class DataModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)  

        self.items = Base("Base")
        car0 = Car("Car0",  self.items)
        car1 = Car("Car1",  car0)
        car2 = Car("Car2",  car1)

        plane0 = Plane("Plane0",  self.items)
        plane1 = Plane("Plane1",  plane0)
        plane2 = Plane("Plane2",  plane1) 

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def getNodeFromIndex(self, index):    
        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            if node:
                return node            
        return self.items

    def parent(self, index):
        node = self.getNodeFromIndex(index)
        parentNode = node.getParent()
        if parentNode == self.items:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return self.createIndex(parentNode.row(), 0, parentNode)

    def index(self, row, column, parentIndex):
        parentNode = self.getNodeFromIndex(parentIndex)
        childItem = parentNode.child(row)
        if childItem:            
            newIndex=self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
            return newIndex
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            parentNode = self.items
        else:
            parentNode = parent.internalPointer()
        return parentNode.childCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QtCore.QVariant()
        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()
        node=index.internalPointer()

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column==0 and not self.columnCount():
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
            else:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.dataModel=DataModel()

        self.viewA=QtGui.QTableView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)  
        self.show()

    def onClick(self, index):
        node=index.internalPointer()
        print node.name(), node.getParent().name()

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I honestly have very little idea what you are trying to get at here (your question is worded confusingly), however it appears you might be incorrectly conflating parent/child relationships with rows/columns OR your rowcount is incorrect. In short, you appear to have a `plane0` and `car0` item, each with two children. But you have only 2 rows shown in your view, each with 3 columns and none have children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by designing your classes accordingly, but internal pointer ist just something you create with help of `createIndex()` in `QModelIndex`.

See the documentation of [createIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex).

So it's up to you to store something useful in it.