# Model/TableView: Rows vs Columns

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt

To keep things simple and easy to read the Qt widgets were omitted here:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class Node(object):    
    def __init__(self, name, parentNode=None):        
        self.name=name
        self._children=[]
        self._parentNode=parentNode
        if parentNode:
            parentNode._children.append(self)

    def getChildNode(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def childrenCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.log()
    def log(self, tabLevel=-1):
        output     = ""
        tabLevel += 1
        for i in range(tabLevel):
            output += "\t"
        output += "|------" + self.name + "\n"
        for child in self._children:
            output += child.log(tabLevel)
        tabLevel -= 1
        output += "\n"
        return output

class NodeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NodeModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self._rootNode = Node("Root")
        nodeA0 = Node("nodeA0",  self._rootNode)
        nodeA1 = Node("nodeA1",  nodeA0)
        nodeA2 = Node("nodeA2",  nodeA1)

        nodeB0 = Node("nodeB0",  self._rootNode)
        nodeB1 = Node("nodeB1",  nodeB0)
        nodeB2_0 = Node("nodeB2_0",  nodeB1) 
        nodeB2_1 = Node("nodeB2_1",  nodeB1) 

        print self._rootNode

    def rowCount(self, parentIndex):    
        if not parentIndex.isValid():
            parentNode = self._rootNode
        else:
            parentNode = parentIndex.internalPointer()
        return parentNode.childCount()

    def columnCount(self, parent):   
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):     
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        node = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return node.name()                  

    def getNode(self, index):    
        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            if node:
                return node            
        return self._rootNode

    def parent(self, index):   
        node = self.getNode(index)
        parentNode = node._parentNode

        if parentNode == self._rootNode:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentNode.row(), 0, parentNode)        

    def index(self, row, column, parentIndex):
        print  row, column  
        parentNode = self.getNode(parentIndex)
        childNode = parentNode.getChildNode(row)

        if childNode:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childNode)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

myModel=NodeModel()
```

Here is a diagram of underlying data structure:

```
|------Root
    |------nodeA0
        |------nodeA1
            |------nodeA2



    |------nodeB0
        |------nodeB1
            |------nodeB2_0

            |------nodeB2_1
```

**Step 1**

I start by querying a top-level `QModelIndex` from Row 1 and Column 0:

```
nodeB0_modelIndex=myModel.index(1, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex())
```

where `1` is a Row number, `0` is a Column number and `QtCore.QModelIndex()` is an empty QModelIndex (this is how we let the model know that we request a **top-level** `QModelIndex`).

Next using `QModelIndex` `.internalPointer()` method I query a data-variable linked to a received `QModelIndex`:

```
nodeB0=nodeB0_modelIndex.internalPointer()
print 'Confirming: top-level node at row 1 column 0: "%s"'%nodeB0.name
```

The confirmation prints I get a "correct" variable back:

> Confirming: top-level node at row 1 column 0: "nodeB0"

**Step 2**

Now having a top-level `QModelIndex` linked to "nodeB0" I can propagate down the data hierarchy to `nodeB1` and then to `nodeB2_0` and `nodeB2_1`. Once again querying `QModelIndex` I will be using `myModel.index()` method supplying it with three arguments: Row number, Column number (both numbers are relative to the `QModelIndex`-parent) and the `QModelIndex`-parent itself as a third argument:

```
nodeB1_modelIndex=myModel.index(0, 0, nodeB0_modelIndex)
nodeB1=nodeB1_modelIndex.internalPointer()
print 'Confirming: node B at row 0 column 0: "%s"'%nodeB1.name

nodeB2_0_modelIndex=myModel.index(0, 0, nodeB1_modelIndex)
nodeB2_0=nodeB2_0_modelIndex.internalPointer()
print 'Confirming: node B at row 0 column 0: "%s"'%nodeB2_0.name

nodeB2_1_modelIndex=myModel.index(1, 0, nodeB1_modelIndex)
nodeB2_1=nodeB2_1_modelIndex.internalPointer()
print 'Confirming: node B at row 1 column 0: "%s"'%nodeB2_1.name
```

So far I have been working with Row numbers only. For the Column numbers I was using 0.
Looking at my underlying data structure defined in the `self._rootNode` I can see why:

The model's Row numbers are eventually used to query a Node-instance stored in `_children` list variable:

```
def getChildNode(self, row):
    return self._children[row]
```

where `row` argument corresponds to both Model's row and list variable index number - an ordered number of elements stored in a typical list variable.

Question: Looking at my underlying data structure I can't find a way to implement the **Column** numbers. How, where and why I should be using Columns?

## Edited Later:

I was rereading my own question when I came to an idea... What if the answer to my question is: we use Row numbers when we intend to place the node-items vertically within QTableView with the zero numbered item at the Row # 0 and all others items going down (so there is only single Column # 0 in use). If we decide to position node-items horizontally we use Columns numbers instead. This way the first item is leftmost. And all the following items are placed next to each other on a right side. Then only a single Row # 0 is used.

With QTableView we use either Row or Column numbers. Not the both. So we design the underlying data structure variable and a model handling it accordingly. Am I correct?

[image]

Comment: "How, where and why I should be using Columns?" I don't see how you expect someone to answer that question without explaining what you want displayed. Maybe you shouldn't have any columns? Maybe you do have data to be displayed in columns. It all depends what YOU want, which you haven't told us. Without context, it is near impossible to guess at a solution. Also, is this basically the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870213/how-internalpointer-method-works), and have you abandoned that question?

Comment: The number of columns is the depth of the tree, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have a tree model that you want to display in a table view instead of a tree view.
Since the easiest solution to display data in a table view is to use a 2D array (`[[]]`), you could use a [QAbstractProxyModel](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qabstractproxymodel.html) to transform your tree like data model into a 2D array data model.
In this way, implementing `rowCount`, `columnCount`, and `data` is very easy.